# Invalid or unsupported command "list avds", the "android" command is deprecated

Tags: android, selendroid

```
C:\Guru99>java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.11.0-with-dependencies.jar
################# Selendroid #################
################# Configuration in use #################
io.selendroid.SelendroidConfiguration@13221655[
  port=4444
  timeoutEmulatorStart=300000
  supportedApps=[]
  verbose=false
  emulatorPort=5560
  deviceScreenshot=false
  selendroidServerPort=8080
  keystore=<null>
  emulatorOptions=<null>
  registrationUrl=<null>
  proxy=<null>
  serverHost=<null>
  keepAdbAlive=false
  noWebViewApp=false
  noClearData=false
  sessionTimeoutSeconds=1800
  forceReinstall=false
  logLevel=ERROR
]
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:26 AM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
INFO: Starting selendroid-server port 4444
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:26 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver356317634035924213.apk META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:27 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver356317634035924213.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:27 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver356317634035924213.apk META-INF/CERT.SF
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:27 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver356317634035924213.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.SF
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:27 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver356317634035924213.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.RSA
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:27 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver356317634035924213.apk META-INF/NDKEYSTO.SF
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:27 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver356317634035924213.apk META-INF/NDKEYSTO.RSA
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:28 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\resigned-android-driver356317634035924213.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\ceinfo\.android\debug.keystore C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver356317634035924213.apk androiddebugkey
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:28 AM io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder signTestServer
INFO: App signing output: jar signed.

Warning:
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2048-01-01) or after any future revocation date.

Jan 15, 2018 11:36:28 AM io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder signTestServer
INFO: The app has been signed: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\resigned-android-driver356317634035924213.apk
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:31 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
Jan 15, 2018 11:36:31 AM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
SEVERE: Error occurred while building server: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
io.selendroid.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
        at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator.listAvailableAvds(DefaultAndroidEmulator.java:113)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.DeviceStore.initAndroidDevices(DeviceStore.java:104)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initAndroidDevices(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:160)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:83)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:61)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:50)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.java:105)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
        at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator.listAvailableAvds(DefaultAndroidEmulator.java:111)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: **************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

Invalid or unsupported command "list avds"

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk

        ... 9 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: io.selendroid.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:60)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.java:105)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
        at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator.listAvailableAvds(DefaultAndroidEmulator.java:113)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.DeviceStore.initAndroidDevices(DeviceStore.java:104)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initAndroidDevices(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:160)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:83)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:61)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:50)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:49)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: C:\Users\ceinfo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
        at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator.listAvailableAvds(DefaultAndroidEmulator.java:111)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: **************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

Invalid or unsupported command "list avds"

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk

        ... 9 more
```

when i want to run selendroid on my system, it is not running, it is not fetching any sdk related information. There is some error to run selendroid on port 4444. i have seen almost every post but there is not satisfied answer, they are not related to this problem, i am using selendroid dependency jar file version 0.11.0 and android studio 2.3.3

Comment: your sdk is not compatible with selendroid version. Downgrade your android SDK, especially the `tools` folder inside your SDK

Comment: how do i downgrade sdk version as it is inbuilt with android studio

Answer (score 0):

Change SelendroidStandaloneServer code to adapt new android cmds: 
change shellcmd android list avds to android list avd

Line 148 of io.selendroid.standalone.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator

```
CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine(AndroidSdk.android());
cmd.addArgument("list", false);
//cmd.addArgument("avds", false);
cmd.addArgument("avd", false);
```

Rebuild selendroid on androidstudio again and run SelendroidStandaloneServer.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to older android sdk that supports ALL android cmds => More risks/bugs on using Old Android Studio and Old Gradle and old AndroidSDK